# Mongodb on duplicate key update

Tags: php, mongodb

I created group index to collection by ensureIndex method.

I using update method for data insert, but I have problem bulk data insert,

I don't understand this "push" or "addToSet" using by "each" key.

I need Query for php arrays syntax.

```
db.collection.update(
  <query> ( here, how I use the query on bulk insert ? ),
  {
    $addToSet: {
      <field1>: { $each: [ <value1>, <value2> ... ] },
      <field2>: { $each: [ <value1>, <value2> ... ] },
      <field2>: { $each: [ <value1>, <value2> ... ] }
    },
    {$inc : {file_hit : 1}}
  },
  {upsert : true, multi : true}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) and [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) update operators both append values to an array field. `$push` is analogous to doing `$arr[] = $value` in PHP, as the value is always appended. `$addToSet` will only add a value to an array if it does not already exist -- thereby treating the array like a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29).

Typically, both `$push` and `$addToSet` expect one value for a field. If you wish to specify multiple values, you can wrap those with the [`$each`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/each/#op._S_each) operator, which you were doing above in your code example. Before MongoDB 2.4, you might have used the [`$pushAll`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pushAll/) operator, but it has since been deprecated in favor of `$each`. The linked documentation for each of these operators should clearly explain how they function with respect to one another.

If we translate your original JS example into PHP, using [MongoCollection::update()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php):

```
$collection->update(
  [], /* update query */
  [
    '$addToSet' => [
      [ 'field1' => [ '$each' => [ $value1, $value2 ]],
      [ 'field2' => [ '$each' => [ $value3, $value4 ]],
    ],
    '$inc' => [ 'file_hit' => 1 ],
  ],
  [ 'multi' => true ]
);
```

*Note: I'm using PHP 5.4's short array syntax above. Earlier versions will need to use `array()` in place of `[]`.*

I fixed a few errors that were in your JS example. Firstly, I removed the object around `$inc`, since update operators belong at the top level of the second parameter. `$inc` should sit parallel to `$addToSet`.

I also removed the `upsert` option, since that is not compatible with `multi`. Logically, `upsert` decides to update a document if it exists, or insert it otherwise. That is fundamentally incompatible with a multi-document update. MongoDB's [db.collection.update()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) documentation explains both options in more detail.